# Multiple frequent visits to US from Canada on B2

Tags: visas, usa, repeat-visits, canadian-residents

So I just recently moved to Vancouver for an internship. Previously I lived in Toronto. I am a Canadian PR, in process of getting the passport. Since I moved I have been frequently visiting cousins in Seattle. Usually it’s been every other weekend but this time I will be going consecutive weekends. I always come with my return bus ticket booked, and obviously have to go to the office on Monday, so I usually return on Sundays. Are CBP going to give me extra hassle because I am taking so many frequent trips? I genuinely spend time with my cousins and they basically show me all around Seattle

Answer (score 2):

CBP doesn't care about this at all. They like frequent visitors who come for a weekend and then leave. Or come for the day. There are indeed frequent visitors who cross *daily*. The important bit, of course, is that you leave each time.